# How to set default values in angular reactive form using previously saved object?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, reactive

My reactive form is almost done. At least it's basic logic. I have only one problem. According to the task I need all inputs to be set using previous data that user entered, if that data exists of course. The data should be kept and stored and rendered if components are switched. I mannaged to save all data into an object in a component, but after page refresh everything is gone. 
How can I tackle with this problem?

My code is as follows:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-form',
      templateUrl: './form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
    })
    export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
      signUpForm: FormGroup;
      countries = [
        new FormControl('USA'),
        new FormControl('India')
      ];

      savedForm: {
        city: string,
        code: number,
        country: string,
        email: string,
        firstName: string,
        id: string,
        lastName: string,
        phone: number,
        state: string;
      }

      statesUSA = [new FormControl('New York'), new FormControl('California')];
      statesIndia = [new FormControl('Andhra Pradesh'), new FormControl('Goa')]

      citiesNY = [new FormControl('Albany'), new FormControl('New York City')];
      citiesCali = [new FormControl('Sacramento'), new FormControl('Los Angeles'), new FormControl('San Francisco')];
      citiesAndhra = [new FormControl('Visakhapatnam'), new FormControl('Amaravati')];
      citiesGoa = [new FormControl('Panaji'), new FormControl('Vasco da Gama')];

      @ViewChild('phoneInput', {static: false}) phoneInput: ElementRef;
      public mask:any = {
        mask: '+{38}(0__)000-00-00',
        lazy: false
      }

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({
          'firstName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇ]{2,32}$/iu)]),
          'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/^\S{2,255}@\S+\.\S+$/iu)]),
          'country': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
          'phone': new FormControl(null),
          'lastName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇ]{2,32}$/iu)]),
          'id': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\b[A-Za-z_]{5,30}\b/)]),
          'state': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
          'city': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
          'code': new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern(/\b[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,10}\b/)])
        });

        this.signUpForm.setValue(this.savedForm);
      }


      onBlur(blur: boolean) {

      }

      onSubmit() {
        if(this.signUpForm.status === 'VALID') {
          this.

savedForm = this.signUpForm.value;
      console.log(this.savedForm);
    }
  }

  onReset() {

  }

  onChange() {
   (<FormGroup>this.signUpForm.get('state').value) = null;
   (<FormGroup>this.signUpForm.get('city').value) = null;
  }

  onOpen(controlName: string) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Service`, components shouldn't fetch or save data directly they should focus on presenting data and delegate data access to a service.

**Step 1**

Create a service :

**src/services/storeService.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StoreService {

  public savedForm

}
```

When you provide the service at the root level, Angular creates a single, shared instance of StoreService and injects into any class that asks for it. Registering the provider in the @Injectable metadata also allows Angular to optimize an app by removing the service if it turns out not to be used after all.

**Step 2**

In your component inject the newly created service in the constructor:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent {
  signUpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private storeService: StoreService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({
      'firstName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇ]{2,32}$/iu)]),
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/^\S{2,255}@\S+\.\S+$/iu)]),
      'country': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'phone': new FormControl(null),
      'lastName': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[а-яА-ЯёЁіІїЇ]{2,32}$/iu)]),
      'id': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\b[A-Za-z_]{5,30}\b/)]),
      'state': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'city': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'code': new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern(/\b[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,10}\b/)])
    });

    if (this.storeService.savedForm) this.signUpForm.setValue(this.storeService.savedForm)
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.signUpForm.status === 'VALID') {
      this.storeService.savedForm = this.signUpForm
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know this stuff, but I'm still new to a framework.

Comment: If you refresh the page your app will be reloaded including your services, and your data will be lost.

Comment: if you really want the data to persist after reloading without saving it to db, you should save it in ```localstorage```

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask if you have any issues with it.